# Java RMI UnmarshalException and AWS EC2 Server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, client-server, rmi

I'm trying to implement the RMI Compute PI tutorial found on the Sun/Oracle website [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/server.html). The server is located on an Amazon windows EC2 Server. The client is located on my personal computer at home. Just to keep things simple, I have disabled the firewall on the server and open all the port on the EC2 security group. I can ping the machine, have access to files, etc... My aim is just to have a basic RMI program worked on AWS. I will oversee security issues later.

Lauching the server is not a problem. And it's correctly bound to the RMI Registry. I'm using the following command to launch it :

`java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=C:\AWSTest\security.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/AWS/Sources/sun-rmi-tutorial-server/bin/ file:/C:/AWS/Sources/sun-rmi-tutorial-common/bin/ -classpath C:\AWS\Sources\sun-rmi-tutorial-server\bin;C:\AWS\Sources\sun-rmi-tutorial-common\bin engine.ComputeEngine ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

- The RMI registry is started on the server side.
- I have declared a new security manager on the server side `System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager())`
- I'm using a `security.policy` file where I'm granted all permission.

When I'm launching the client side, on my local computer, I'm ending with an UnmarshalException:

```
ComputePi exception: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: engine.ComputeEngine_Stub
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: engine.ComputeEngine_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at client.ComputePi.main(ComputePi.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: engine.ComputeEngine_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:453)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:184)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:216)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    ... 3 more
```

Do you have any suggestions of what is wrong ? Why can't the client find the correct Stub ? I'm using Eclipse Juno, Genady RMI Plugin and Java 1.7.0_07.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT 1 :**

The Java workspace is organized around 3 projects : the Client side, the Server Side and a Common project where both the server and the client share classes.

- I can read the remote registry from my local computer. The RMI plugin can connect remotely to the server and inspect the registry.
- If instead of making 3 projects I put all the classes under the same project, everything is working fine... But I notice that no stubs where generated (or needed).
- If, on the client side, I'm putting a reference in the classpath to the server classes (everything being build locally), i have a connection timeout error instead of the unmarshalling error.

  ComputePi exception: Connection refused to host: XX.XXX.XX.XX; nested exception is: 
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: XX.XXX.XXX; nested exception is: 
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
      at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
      at engine.ComputeEngine_Stub.executeTask(ComputeEngine_Stub.java:35)
      at client.ComputePi.main(ComputePi.java:19)
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
      at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
      at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
      at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
      ... 5 more

Answer (score 1):

You haven't deployed the stub class to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please be more explicit ? Just to add some precision to my problem. The Java workspace is organized around 3 projects : the Client side, the Server Side and a Common project where both the server and the client share classes.

Comment: @BlackLabrador I cannot agree that any futher precision is required. Either you have deployed your stub class to the client or you haven't, and you haven't. It is a binary state. Obviously the stub class belongs in the shared JAR file, and equally obviously it isn't in there.

Comment: Hi, thanks you answer. What might be obvious for an experienced Java RMI programmer might not be for a newbie. I don't know how to deploy a RMI program... which might explain my problems. it was not obvious that the client side should incorporate the server JAR file... I thought that all the purpose of RMI was to make this available to the client via the registry. As long as the stub was exported on the server side, the client should find it. When I'm looking at the config file that comes with the example, I don't see any ref to the server JAR on the codebase. I have added Edit 2 in my comment

Comment: @BlackLabrador You had already figured out what you are now claiming isn't obvious, that there must be some classes in common between client and server. You just didn't get them all right. The error message was sufficient to tell you that.